# QGIS Composer layer missing after export to PDF or PNG

Tags: qgis, layers, export, print-composer

I have a couple of raster layers in QGIS 3.28.2 Firenze. One layer is in Hillshade mode and the second one (on top ) is configured as Pseudocolor monoband and has mixing mode set as Multiply so the hillshade shows and the map gets the shadows that give a 3d look. Everything looks fine in the QGIS main screen and in the composer screen but when I export the composition to PDF or as a PNG image the hillshade mixing disapears and only the Pesudocolor is visible.

This is how it looks in the composer screen:

[image: Composer screen capture]

And this is what I get when exported:

[image: Image exported]

I tried to export asPNG and PDF, tried to lower the export resolution, invert the layers order, close and open QGIS and export again. It keeps exporting a flat image with no hillshade.

Comment: Afaik mixing is a poor choice for exporting maps. Some versions ago "mixed" layers even prevented map creation.

Comment: Oh! Do you know if there is any alternative method or workaround to apply a hillshade shading over a raster?

Comment: Have you tried `export as displayed` on the hillshade layer and then using that layer for map creation?

Comment: I just found there's an open issue in Github for this bug... 
 "Layer blending mode reset on export for all file types #50526" 
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/50526

Comment: Until the bug is addressed can you get satisfactory results by making your pseudocolor partially transparent over the hillshade?

Comment: Yes, that works to some extent. 
The outcome is not identical as it results in a decrease in color saturation. Also the layer color reference in a composition does not align with the final rendered map. Nevertheless, it is still preferable to having no solution at all.

Answer (score 1):

I found that there's an issue in Github for this bug.

["Layer blending mode reset on export for all file types #50526"](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/50526)